# Mapping List items to org.apache.spark.sql.Column type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to sum a list of columns in my Dataframe of type org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame and create a new column 'sums' and dataframe 'out'.

I can do this quite easily if I list the columns by hand, for example, this works

```
val columnsToSum = List(col("led zeppelin"), col("lenny kravitz"), col("leona lewis"), col("lily allen"))
val out = df3.withColumn("sums", columnsToSum.reduce(_ + _))
```

However, if I wish to do this by pulling the column names directly from the dataframes the items in the list object are not the same and I am unable to do this, for example

```
val columnsToSum = df2.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType]).map(_.name).patch(0, Nil, 1).toList // arrays are mutable (remove "user" from list)
println(tmpArr)
>> List(a perfect circle, abba, ac/dc, adam green, aerosmith, afi, ...

// Trying the same method
val out = df3.withColumn("sums", columnsToSum.reduce(_ + _))

>> found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val out = df3.withColumn("sums", tmpArr.reduce(_ + _))found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val out = df3.withColumn("sums", tmpArr.reduce(_ + _))
```

How do I do this type of conversion? I've tried:

```
List(a perfect circle, abba, ac/dc, ...).map(_.Column)
List(a perfect circle, abba, ac/dc, ...).map(_.spark.sql.Column)
List(a perfect circle, abba, ac/dc, ...).map(_.org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
```

Which haven't worked
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a column object from a string by using function col (you are actually already using it in your first snippet).

So this should work:

```
columnsToSum.map(col).reduce(_ + _)
```

or move verbose version:

```
columnsToSum.map(c => col(c)).reduce(_ + _)
```